# Plotting two variables against each other but getting two lines instead of just one

Tags: python, fft

For my physics Research Practicum I'm analyzing the resonance frequency of a wine glass, which involves importing an audio file and taking its Fourier transform (using scipy.fftpack). So everything is going well, but when I plot the Fourier transform, I get two lines: one is the plot you would expect, but the other one is a horizontal line ([see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAAwN.png)). I've looked into the variables I'm plotting but nothing seems out of the ordinary there.

Here's the code (you'll need [this .wav file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bxcKqbk3wC-ZjBq_KmPRo49SxDBhRASM/view?usp=sharing) (watch out for your ears, headphone users!)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile as wav
from scipy.fftpack import fft,fftfreq
import numpy as np

#Read the .wav file here:  ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ
rate, data = wav.read('C:\\Users\\ilike\\OneDrive\\Documenten\\RP\\RP2\\Bewerkte .wav files\\0 ml_bewerkt.wav')


#Take the Fourier transform of the .wav file. Take the log10 of it and normalize (so Fourier_ynorm is between 0 and 1) 
Fourier_y = np.log(abs(fft(data[:,0])))
Fourier_ynorm = Fourier_y/max(Fourier_y)
Fourier_x = fftfreq(len(data), 1/rate)
#The x-axis is in Hz, so a 1200 Hz beep would give a peak at 1200 and -1200

#These two lines plot the Fourier transform, but there is a weird horizontal line at y = 0.3
plt.plot(Fourier_x, Fourier_ynorm)
plt.xlim(1200,1400)
```

I'd like to know how the horizontal line got there and how to remove it.

Edit: I have fixed the problem using fftshift. Thanks for everyone who helped (and sorry for the newbish question)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the plot of `Fourier_x` alone looks like:

```
plt.plot(Fourier_x)
```

[image]

Looks like you have the same signal repeated twice in the wav file?

The horizonal line is an artefact of having a non-monotonic `Fourier_x`, I think

A simple solution is to change your plotting command to

```
plt.plot(Fourier_x, Fourier_ynorm, '.')
```

this looks like:

[image]

A more advanced solution is to understand/fix the fact that you have what looks like a repeated signal in the wav file

Comment: Hmm interesting. I have indeed noticed that if I plot Fourier_ynorm by itself, the horizontal line isn't there, so Fourier_x does seem to be the culprit.
Though I wonder, the second (negative) part of Fourier_x should be irrelevant, as in the plot I'm only using the positive part of Fourier_x. But if I plot Fourier_x[0:2000] against Fourier_ynorm[0:2000], the line dissappears. So I guess I could cut Fourier_x so that only the positive part is used.